# What does 'ages of ages' mean, specifically?

Tags: church-history, terminology, eastern-orthodox

I run into this phrase a lot in the Orthodox church, particularly as part of the longer phrase 'and unto ages of ages'. I understand that, generally, this means 'for a long time'. However, what does it mean specifically? Where did the phrase come from and what is its history? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The phrase comes from the Bible. It’s a fairly wooden translation of the Greek idiom *εἰς τοὺς αἰῶνας τῶν αἰώνων*. Many English translations instead use “forever and ever” or something along those lines, which is more in line with English idiom.

As for precisely where it originated, I haven’t been able to find any uses in classical Greek, though perhaps someone with better searching abilities can help with that.  [Liddell-Scott-Jones Greek-English Lexicon](http://stephanus.tlg.uci.edu/lsj/#eid=2945&context=lsj&action=hw-list-click) (a lexicon including classical Greek) discusses several related idiomatic phrases using a double αἰών with various prepositions. Interestingly, all of the examples given there are within the LXX. <sup>1</sup>

*Εἰς τοὺς αἰῶνας τῶν αἰώνων* itself appears just once in the Greek translation of Hebrew scriptures,<sup>3</sup>  in Psalm 83[84]:5[4]<sup>2</sup> where it translates really nothing (עוֹד ≈ *still* or *yet*), so the idiom appears to be native to Greek. It shows up 18 times in the New Testament (NA-28, including bracketed):

- Galatians 1:5, Philippians 4:20, 1 Timothy 1:17, 2 Timothy 4:18
- Hebrews 13:21
- 1 Peter 4:11
- Revelation 1:6, 1:18, 4:9, 4:10, 5:13, 7:12, 10:6, 11:15, 15:7, 19:3, 20:10, 22:5

All of the examples from the epistles are contained within a *doxology*, a fitting term because all of them ascribe *δόξα* (*doxa* ≈ “glory") to one or more persons of the Godhead, with the basic structure: *ᾧ ἡ δόξα εἰς τοὺς αἰῶνας τῶν αἰώνων* (“to whom be the glory forever and ever”).

The phrase appears to have been pulled from these Biblical doxologies into [Orthodox Liturgies](http://www.goarch.org/chapel/liturgical_texts/liturgy_hchc-el). You’ll also run across the Latin version of the same: [*in saecula saeculorum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_saecula_saeculorum).

---

<sub>1. Koine Greek witnessed increased laxity in the meaning of prepositions and tended to add them in where classical Greek found the naked cases sufficient, so it’s not especially surprising that the development would go in this direction.</sub>

<sub>2. Numbering is according to LXX with English in brackets.</sub>

<sub>3. And once additionally in the Greek 4 Macc 18:4.</sub>

Comment: And then of course there's "world without end".

Answer (score 7):

**Aion/ Aeon**

A closer-to-original-form translation of *unto ages of ages* is "**into [the] aeons of [the] aeons**," from Greek ***eis tous aionas ton aionon***, occurring regularly as part of an ovation formula in the writings commonly called the New Testament of the Bible. The most popular English translations of these writings render the statement into a most imprecise phrase "forever and ever", which implies, for the majority of modern readers, a linear duration of time that goes on without end, generally in some "forward" direction.

In modern English an aeon [or "eon" in the USA] is an immeasurably long period of time, and is, according to the 2012 Digital Edition of the Collins English Dictionary, "the longest division of geological time, comprising two or more eras".

In Ancient Greek an *aion*, from which, via Latinisation, we get English *aeon*, is a *lifetime*, a *lifespan* or a *generation*, whether of a human being (roughly several decades), of an animal (such as a housefly, which lives only about a month or so) or of an empire (which could last centuries). According to the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=eon), this word is cognate with Old Norse *ævi*, "lifetime," related to Modern English *ever*.

One way to interpret *eis tous aionas ton aionon*, therefore, would be "into lifetimes of lifetimes". For some of the few English Bible publications which have opted to render the expression more literally rather than use the "forever and ever" interpretation, these are their versions of a portion of Revelation 1.18 (with my emphases added), in which the writer sees "one who looks like a son of man" who says to him:

> I became dead, and lo! living am I **for the eons of the eons**. (Amen!)
>   And I have the keys of death and of the unseen.
>   <sub>[Concordant Literal Version (CLV)](http://studybible.info/CLV/Revelation%201:18)</sub>
>
> I became dead, and behold, I am living **to the ages of ages**,
>   and have the keys of death and of hades.
>   <sub>[1890 Darby Bible](https://www.bible.com/bible/478/rev.1.18)</sub>
>
> I did become dead, and, lo, I am living **to the ages of the ages**. Amen!
>   and I have the keys of the hades and of the death.
>   <sub>[Young's Literal Translation (YLT)](https://www.bible.com/bible/821/rev.1.18)</sub>
>
> I died; but I am now alive **until the Ages of the Ages**,
>   and I have the keys of the gates of Death and of Hades!
>   <sub>[The 1912 Weymouth New Testament (WNT)](http://biblehub.com/wey/revelation/1.htm)</sub>

**The World(s) [in Sæcula Sæculorum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_saecula_saeculorum)**

In the English of the late 1300s this Scripture verse looks remarkably different, and would imply something closer to modern quantum physics if we applied 21st-century definitions thereto. In [John Wycliffe's 1385 New Testament](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+1%3A18&version=WYC), it says:

> *Y was deed; and lo! Y am lyuynge in to worldis of worldis,
>
>   and Y haue the keyes of deth and of helle.*

“I was dead; and look! I am living **into worlds of worlds**,
and I have the keys of death and of hell.”
<sup>(*Emphasis added.*)</sup>

Wycliffe was translating from Latin, from the Vulgate Bible, which renders the expression in question as ***in sæcula sæculorum***. In Roman times a *sæculum* was a period quite similar to what would we would call an age or a generation. It eventually got attached to the notion of a time-span of this mortal world, and by Wycliffe's time *sæculum* meant "world," from which we get the English word "secular" and its modern interpretation as "worldly" or "of this world" over against the things which are transcendent, divine or immortal. One translation of *in sæcula sæculorum*, offered by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_(I)#in_saeculo), is "down to the times of the times".

In the first quarter of the 7th century AD, Isidorus Hispalensis, the Archbishop of Seville in Spain<sup>1</sup>, published an encyclopaedia called the *Etymologiæ*, "Etymologies," in which he quotes *De catechizandis rudibus*, by Augustinus Hipponensis<sup>2</sup>, from a couple of generations preceding him. There is reference therein to what were considered to be [the Six Ages of the World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Ages_of_the_World), with a seventh one often interpreted as "the Sabbath Age," the World to Come, so that the ultimate age of the universe ends up being one "divine week" composed of seven days, each day lasting about a thousand years long but with the seventh one being endless.

In Book 5, Chapter 38, Section 5, the *Etymologiæ* say:

> The term 'age' properly is used in two ways:
>   either as an age of
>   a human – as infancy, youth, old age –
>   or as an age of the world,
>   whose first age is from Adam to Noah;
>   second from Noah to Abraham;
>   third from Abraham to David;
>   fourth from David to the exile of Judah
>   to Babylon;
>   fifth from then [the Babylonian captivity], to the advent
>   of our Savior in the flesh;
>   sixth, which is now under way, to when the
>   world itself comes to an end.
>   The succession of these ages through
>   generations and reigns is thus reviewed.

The word translated<sup>3</sup> "age" here, is however, *ætas*<sup>4</sup> rather than *sæculum*, the latter of which is defined in Section 1 of the same chapter as follows:

> *Saecula* consist of generations, and hence the term *saeculum*, because they 'follow' (*sequi* <sup>5</sup>) one after another, for when some pass
>   away, others take their place. Some call a *saeculum* a period of
>   fifty years, which the Hebrews call a jubilee.

---

<sub>1. Isidorus, or Isidore of Seville, is venerated as a saint in both the Roman Catholic and the Eastern Orthodox Churches; is, in the Occident, considered to be the last of the Church Fathers; and [might currently be in the process](http://catholicism.org/patron-saint-for-the-internet-isidore-of-seville.html) of officially being recognised as the patron saint of the Internet and of computer programmers, technicians and users.

2. "On Catechising the Uninitiated," by Augustine of Hippo

3. In [*The* Etymologies *of Isidore of Seville*](http://sfponline.org/Uploads/2002/st%20isidore%20in%20english.pdf), by Stephen A. Barney, W.J. Lewis, J.A. Beach & Oliver Berghof, with the collaboration of Muriel Hall

4. From which comes the word *æternitas*, "eternity," which originally did *not* mean "endless time."

5. Cf. the English word *sequence*.</sub>

---

**A Poetic Expression**

In his book [*Time and Eternity: A Biblical Study*](http://allinclusivegospel.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/TIME-AND-ETERNITY-Biblical-Study-on-AIONIAN-G.-T.-Stevenson.pdf), G.T. Stevenson says that *eis tous aionas ton aionon* is a **polytotonic superlative** based on a normal Hebraic or Semitic expression similar to other designations like *King of Kings*, *Lord of Lords*, *Holy of Holies* and *Song of Songs*.

In a most self-explanatory manner, "Holy of Holies" is also often rendered as "Most Holy Place." Similarly the Song of Songs is, in Stevenson's interpretation of the expression, the finest song.

The Ethiopian Emperor's title was "King of Kings" because he was a king who ruled over a number of provinces on the coast of the Red Sea, each of which had its own king. The Irish High King was a king of or over other kings in Ireland. Within a certain region or empire, therefore, the King of Kings would be the highest or most powerful king. The same goes for a "Lord of Lords."

**Age of Ages**

Technically, however, each of the above is describing a singular thing. The plural of this is what *Ages of Ages* represents. If a bunch of emperors got together to hang out, then we would have a meeting of some "Kings of Kings."

Stevenson understands the singular form of the expression in question—Age of Ages (occurring only one time in the Bible, in [Ephesians 3.21](https://www.bible.com/bible/821/eph.3.21))—to mean "best Age," which could also be said to be a very good or great Age. (Note how "Golden Age" is a term from Greco-Roman mythology used now to refer to what is considered to be the best times of a certain phenomenon, e.g. the golden age of jazz. In this way "the golden age" is an *age of ages* : an extremely memorable, nostalgia-inducing time-period).

**The Plural (of the Plural)**

On the other hand, perhaps it is to be taken *quant*itatively rather than *quali*tatively. Just as an empire contains within itself a number of kingdoms so too perhaps an Age of Ages is a larger time-span containing smaller spans. And so the [plural] *Ages of [the] Ages* would be a combination or collection of these larger time-spans.

In modern Western studies, for example, the 3000-year period of Pharaonic Egypt is commonly divided, broadly, into *Old Kingdom*, *Middle Kingdom* and *New Kingdom*. Each of these three Kingdom periods is then subdivided into dynasties, each referring to the time that a certain family was ruling the empire, which could be as brief as the reign of only one king (such as the 28th Dynasty under [Amenirdisu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amyrtaeus)) or as long as the domination of fifteen monarchs (such as the 14th Dynasty, featuring famous characters like [Hatshepsut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatshepsut) and [Tutankhamun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutankhamun)).

You might then say that therefore the larger divisions of time in view here are Egypt's Ages of Ages, i.e. the *Kingdom* periods containing the *Dynasty* periods. This of course could be extrapolated further downwards (into years of reign, months of those years, weeks, days, hours, etc) or upwards (Pharaonic Egypt into all Ancient Egyptian history and so on) so that you can have ages within ages within *other* ages.

**English, and an Example from an Indian Concept**

While the English "ages of [the] ages" might come off quite clunky and generally unintelligible (at least to modern speakers), the word "age" is cognate with ancient Sanskrit *yuga*, from which we get Modern Hindi *yug*. In ancient Indian thought a yuga is an extraordinarily long period of time (the current yuga, in which we dwell, will last a total of 432 millennia, according to the most mainstream version of this view) which is composed of smaller time-units, such as a *caraṇa*, and which is part of a combination of bigger units of time, such as a *Mahāyuga*, "Big" or "Great *Yuga*" (composed of four yugas). This forms an extremely elaborate system of time-measurements that make up the history of the universe and which could quite appropriately be called *ages of ages* in the sense of time-spans within time-units within yet more time-divisions.

The Pavitr Baaibil, a Romanised Hindi translation of the Bible, has, in [the Book of Prakashaitavakya [Revelation] 1.18](https://www.bible.com/bible/820/rev.1.18), the "one who is like a son of man" saying that he is alive *yuganuyug*, commonly interpreted as "forevermore" in English. This, however, is more literally something like "*yuga* upon *yuga*" and which grammatical construction is probably as difficult to render smoothly into English as is its Greek original. Besides which, for it to be closer to "[the] ages of [the] ages" it should actually be *yugon ke yugon*.

**Thinking in Syriac and Hebrew**

The Assyrian Church of the East uses the Pəšîṭtâ, an ancient Syriac version of the Bible, which contains Semitic expressions quite akin to Hebrew. Its version of the expression "into the aeons of the aeons, amen", also from the Book of Gelyānā [Revelation/ Apocalypse], is quite lyrically poetic:

> lə-ālam 'ālmīn 'amīn

This corresponds to the Yiddish and American Ḥasidic way of saying the same thing in Hebrew, such as is employed by Philip Golbe in his [Orthodox Jewish Bible](https://www.bible.com/bible/130/rev.7.12):

> l'Ol[e]mei Olamim, Omein

The modern usage of both the Syriac *ālam* and the Hebrew *olam* imply a concept encompassing both time (age/ yuga) and space (world). This seems to be captured quite roundly in the [Jewish eschatological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_eschatology#.22The_world_to_come.22) dichotomy between *Olam HaZeh*, "The World of the Present," and *Olam HaBa*, "The World to Come."

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks for providing a thorough, well-referenced answer to this question. For more on what this site is all about, please see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Comment: Thanks, Lee. I hope I managed to capture the spirit, as it were, of the site, and that the answer is somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 2):

**What does 'ages of ages' mean, specifically?**

> Galatians 1:5  to whom is the glory to the ages of the ages. Amen. -
>   YLT
>
> Galatians 1:5  To whom be glory for ever and ever. Amen. - KJV
>
> Galatians 1:5  to whom be the glory for ever and ever. Amen - ASV

age = aiōn = an age, variable period of time.

The word aion in Greek is a little hard to pin down. I once read that it could be compared to the English word “great” in variability. It can refer to a period of time less than a lifetime, the reign of a king, or even longer.

The word is frequently translated “eternal” in the KJV. However, this may not always be a correct translation. For example, there is dispute over the description of hell as “eternal” or “age lasting” in the English understanding of the word.

The compound usage of aion (age of ages) such as in the Galatians 1:5 usage may approximate a greater period of time even to what we would consider “eternity”.

Care should be used in making such translations from words whose meaning can vary so significantly. Sometimes additional translation help can be derived from associated verb tense and context.

> Matthew 13:49  So shall it be at the end of the world: the angels
>   shall come forth, and sever the wicked from among the just,

Here the word “world” is aion. The idea being that there is a period of time (an “age”) that will end with the events described.

“Ages of ages” could be seen as constituting a collection of these various periods. For example, if God has designated various ages for his plan for earth, then “ages of ages” could be used to describe a period of time reaching over the entire time or even beyond.

Comment: This answer fails to account for the Eastern Orthodox context.

Answer (score 0):

An "**Age**" is roughly 2,000 years.  The Age of **Aries** or Ram was during the Hebrew & Hindi (think ram horn or bull taurus), the Age of **Pisces** or Fish was during the Christian (think of the image of the Fish Jesus symbol), we are now in the Age of **Aquarius**.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).